# Symfony2 bundle service separation

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

I am trying to implement custom menus for the backend and frontend of the site. Backend and frontend are in the separate bundles. The problem is, it seems that their services are shared (let's say I define one service (knp menu voter) in admin bundle, and it is still active in site bundle). Is this expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK. From docs:

> A service is usually used "globally" [..]

Read more in [Glossary](http://symfony.com/doc/current/glossary.html#term-service) documentation.